# sap.m.DateRangeSelection clear on Mobile Device

Tags: sapui5

I use a DateRangeSelection in my Smartfilterbar. The problem is that when a value is entered, it can not be deleted  anymore on mobile devices. I use sapui5 version 1.32.5 . A workaround would be to implement an extra Button next to the field, and clear it in JavaScript, but thats really ugly.

You can test [example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.5/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.DateRangeSelection/preview) on Chrome if you simulate a mobile device.

Comment: Same goes for `sap.m.DatePicker`... But in your specific scenario, shouldn't there a button to reset your filter? Why don't you use that to clear the `DateRangeSelection`?